# PHP Regex Question

Tags: php, regex

So I'm using Wordpress' database object to store things into tables. One of the drawbacks (or advantages, depending on how you look at it) is that it escapes the single and double quote characters so that:

> ' --> \'
>     "  ---> \"

What regex can I apply to the output to replace all \' with ' and \" with "?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [**stripslashes**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`stripslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
$newstr = stripslashes($str);
```

Note that `stripslashes` will replace `\\` by `\` as well. If you don't want this, you could use `str_replace`:

```
$newstr = str_replace(array('\\\'', '\\"'), array('\'', '"'), $str);
```